# Hello I am new to Scala, I have a question about an anonymous function problem

Tags: scala, function, anonymous-function, higher-order-functions

How this function returns "hello there"? There is definitely something that I am missing here but I don't see it

```
def saySomething(prefix: String) = (s: String) => {  
prefix + " " + s
} 

def saySomethingElse = saySomething("hello")

print(saySomethingElse("there"))
```

I tried tracing how "hello" is substituted by prefix since its the first string being passed in the function "saySomething" but then I don't understand how "there" is attached to the result.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/higher-order-functions.html#functions-that-return-functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breaking it down, it works like this:

```
def saySomething(prefix: String) = (s: String) => {  
  prefix + " " + s
}
```

This is a function called `saySomething` that returns a value:

```
def saySomething(prefix: String) = ???
```

The value it returns is an anonymous function:

```
(s: String) => { prefix + " " + s }
```

Each time you call `saySomething(prefix: String)`, a new function is created and the value of `prefix` is remembered by that new function. So when you call `saySomething("hello")` it remembers `"hello"` and returns this.

```
(s: String) => { "hello" + " " + s } 
def saySomethingElse = (s: String) => { "hello" + " " + s }
```

When you call that new function, you get the final string:

```
saySomethingElse("there")
// == ((s: String) => { "hello" + " " + s })("there")
// == "hello" + " " + "there"
```

You could call it with a different value and get a different result:

```
saySomethingElse("Dolly")
// == ((s: String) => { "hello" + " " + s })("Dolly")
// == "hello" + " " + "Dolly"
```

Note that `saySomethingElse` can just be a `val` not a `def`. It is just a variable that contains a function, it doesn't need to be a function itself.

Comment: "This is a function called `saySomething` that returns a value:" – This is wrong. `saySomething` is *not* a function. It is a *method*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag True but I guess this is a standard figure of speech when describing FP in Scala

Comment: @JörgWMittag The documentation that you linked in the comment section uses "functions" to refer to methods.

Comment: @Tim That was not JörgWMittag, that was me. I gave the link because it's a good idea to remind the OP about the term *higher-order function*. `saySomething` is higher-order.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Apologies, and thanks for your contribution.